# copying files to usb stick never finished

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I tried to copy 3.3GB iso file into a 64GB usb stick, the progress bar show completed but the copying operation windows doesn't closed after almost an hour now and still hanging not closed.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.1-64 bit

does anyone experience this issue?

[image]

Comment: yea, I experience it many times. It copies with normal speed though shows it is copying at unbelievable speed

Comment: Update: it's finally finished after more than an hour and the windows closed.

Comment: i also feel that problem with my ubuntu 12.04...what is that exactly? If it is copying in normal speed why should it illusion us with impressive speed?

Comment: Just to add, does the file operation window happen to close but the usb drive still has activity? Like still copying the information even though the copy dialog is close?

Comment: It's normal, you just have to wait 4 a few hour and it will closed. Mostly cause by hardware. Mine Fix through RAM upgrade.

Comment: This is due to filesystem caching.  The kernel buffers pages to be written to any kind of disk (hard drive, USB drive, etc) in RAM.  From the perspective of the application, the write is complete, but the data has not yet been fully transferred to disk.  The application then waits on the transfer to complete and freezes for a long time while the remaining data is actually stored.

Comment: IMHO, this is a very poor implementation of file copy. Especially the fact that the user isn't shown relevant info on the GUI, about what is happening in the backend. Hope it improves.