# New in ubuntu. Files missing

Tags: files

I installed Ubuntu 16 a few hours ago. 
I was copying my files to my new OS, on to desktop. When I restarted it my files were not there.
I think they are in lost and found.

```
sudo ls -la /home
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 Ago 19 20:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root  4096 Ago 24 09:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x 21 csm csm 4096 Ago 23 10:48 csm
```

**The files were lost the 21st or the 20th.**

```
sudo ls -la /home/csm/Desktop/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 csm csm 4096 Ago 19 20:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 csm csm 4096 Ago 23 10:48 ..
```

Comment: Did you save files within a live USB session?

Comment: Yes, I did not know that I should use another pen.

Comment: `sudo ls -la /home` is the wrong directory too. `sudo ls -la /home/csm/Desktop/` would show contents of your desktop.

Comment: Did  you copy your files using Ubuntu file manager (GUI) or by Terminal? What is the size of your files?

Comment: So probably you restarted your computer before copying finished. See [Why when copying to an external drive the progress window is not correct](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237162/why-when-copying-to-an-external-drive-the-progress-window-is-not-correct)

Comment: That could be it. Next time I will be more carefull. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually [install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) the system before attempting to transfer data. Nothing is saved permanently when running in a live media session as in "Try Ubuntu"

Comment: I instaled Ubuntu. After some shut downs and starts I put the files I needed on to desktop. I restarted and the files were not there. Some instalations done before were.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo ls -la /home` and tell us who you were logged in as when you copied the data.

Comment: With persistent option, something can be saved. Is that option gone now?

Comment: Persistent option when instaling? I think there was no persistent option.