# Startup disk creator appears to be hanging

Tags: startup-disk

I try to create a startup disk with Ubuntu 15.04 64bit on a 16G USB stick.
When I start the "Startup Disk Creator", it will show progress of "Copying files..." until about 49% complete, then hangs forever. No error message shown, no hint if anything is still tried or being done or if I am looking at a corpse. When I press the "Cancel" button I get a confirmation dialog showing "Do you want to quit the installation now?" but when I click "Quit" there, now that dialog also hangs.
After killing the process, when I retried but disabling the extra data region of 1G that it creates by default, the process indicator went to 96% complete and then kept being stuck there.

Answer (score 53):

Startup Disk Creator is known to having issues. Use the **Disks** tool to create the Ubuntu USB installation medium. Open **Disks** and select the USB drive (on the left) to be used as medium.

Then select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right of the application. Choose the
Ubuntu installation **ISO file** - check if the USB drive to write it to is correct and **Start restoring**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The Disks tool works, unlike the Startup Disk Creator which is recommended on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is related to a general problem of copying large files to USB (reported here: [copying files to usb stick never finished](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228590/copying-files-to-usb-stick-never-finished)).

I just waited for ten minutes and it copied over OK. I don't know if cp is actually being unusually slow, or if the speed is just reported incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

### Startup Disk Creator

The **Startup Disk Creator** in versions *before* Ubuntu 16.04 LTS was affected by several bugs. It was an extracting tool. But in 16.04 LTS, the Startup Disk Creator was converted to a cloning tool, which is very reliable.

### Disks

Use **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` to create the Ubuntu installation media in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer versions.

**Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right of the application will clone from the iso file to the target device (the USB stick).

### mkusb

Install and use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions and other main linux distros.

### Link

See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033124/use-dd-cloning-tool-and-ubuntu-installed-on-usb-for-upgrade-or-downgrade-ubuntu/1033130#1033130) with more links and details.