# use dd Cloning Tool and Ubuntu installed on usb for upgrade or downgrade Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, dd, downgrade

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, made some wrong selections while upgrading, Can I use Ubuntu installed on usb  stick (dd   The Native Linux Cloning Tool) to upgrade or downgrade Ubuntu ?

Comment: The newly-created system cloned will have none of your data or settings on it, and the cloning process will destroy all your existing data and settings. You might do better to simply install 18.04 preserving your /home directory, or to clean-install 18.04 then resote data from a backup. Either way, a good backup to protect your data is essential.

Answer (score 1):

**You can clone from the iso file to a USB stick and use that USB stick to boot Ubuntu live and install Ubuntu into the internal drive.**

**`dd`** is a cloning tool, but it is **risky** because it does what you tell it to do without any question. If you tell it to wipe the family pictures it will do it. A minor typing error may create chaos. You must be very careful, **check and double-check** that everything is correct before you press the Enter key.

Instead I recommend a tool with a [final checkpoint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927268/cant-boot-from-usb-drive-after-copying-iso-with-dd/927299#927299),

- in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions: **Startup Disk Creator** alias `usb-creator-gtk`
- in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer versions: **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`
- in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and newer versions and other main linux distros: [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
- in Windows: [**Win32 Disk Imager**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)
- in Windows: [**Rufus**](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) - an extracting tool *and* a cloning tool
- in MacOS: [**Unetbootin**](https://unetbootin.github.io/) - an extracting tool (not a cloning tool)

Comment: Rufus has `dd` functionality and is therefore __both__ an extracting and a cloning tool. If it detects an ISOHybrid, it will ask you whether you want to write it in file extraction or `dd` mode, and it also accepts regular disk images as input (which it will write in `dd` mode).