# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install from USB - How to make bootable USB on Windows?

Tags: system-installation

Just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop ISO file and I want to install from USB.

Do I need to uncompress the ISO file on to the USB, to make it bootable?

Comment: In which OS you have downloaded the ISO image?

Comment: Downloaded it on Windows 10 64 Bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all you need to download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Then double click on the setup and you might see a interface like this:

  [image]
- Click on `Device` to select the USB drive and choose the downloaded ISO image by clicking on the disc icon next to `Create a bootable disk using`.
- Click on Start. After the process finishes and Ready appears like in Screenshot your USB will become bootable.

Comment: It is a Windows only software.

Answer (score 3):

### The easy way is to clone from the iso file to the USB pendrive

There is no need for uncompression. The iso file can be cloned directly as it is, each byte copied directly.

- In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions you can use the **Startup Disk Creator** for this purpose.
- In older versions of Ubuntu and in other linux distros you can use **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or **mkusb**.
- In Windows you can use **Win32 Disk Imager**. All these tools ask for a final confirmation, which make them safer than the command line tool `dd` (but all of them do the job, also `dd`, when set correctly).

### There are also extracting tools, for example

- **Unetbootin** in linux, Windows and MacOS
- **Rufus** in Windows (there is also a cloning mode)
- **mkusb** can also create persistent live drives, but this is a waste of effort, if you only want to use the USB pendrive to try Ubuntu and to install Ubuntu.

### See this link and links from it

[You can clone from the iso file to a USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033124/use-dd-cloning-tool-and-ubuntu-installed-on-usb-for-upgrade-or-downgrade-ubuntu/1033130#1033130)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 you don't need Rufus or any 3rd party tool to make a live bootable Ubuntu UFD. Simply mount the Ubuntu ISO in W10. Copy over all the files other than BOOT to a UFD already formatted in FAT32. Unmount the ISO. Restart the computer and bring up the BIOS boot menu options. Select the UFD, hit Enter and you're good to go.

Comment: For those wondering: "UFD" seems to mean "USB Flash Drive" here.